# Not triggering event when clicking an input (type=file) element in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, reactjs

I'm working with react on an app that has an  hidden to style and input and simulate a click when the styled input has focus

```
class UploadComponent extends React.Component {

 render() {
  return (
   <div className="row">
     <input type="file" className='hidden' ref="fileChooser"/>
     <input type="text" className="input-file" onFocus={this.onFocus.bind(this)} ref="fileName" />
   </div>
  );
 }

 onFocus() {
     this.refs.fileChooser.getDOMNode().click();
 }


}
```

it's working correctly on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox.

I've found that it may be a bug on firefox,

do you know if i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: are you getting any error in the javascript console on Firefox? Is the onFocus event being triggered in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Firefox suppresses invoking `HTMLInputElement.click()` other than from a button-click callback. You even can't use react its synthetic eventsystem (onClick props), for you would be outside the original click-event-subscriber. The only way to get this work, is by subscribe using the native way like this:

The next codesnap should work. Or feel free to use this react-component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/itsa-react-fileuploadbutton

```
class UploadComponent extends React.Component {

   render() {
       return (
           <div className="row">
               <input type="file" className='hidden' ref="fileChooser"/>
               <button ref="selectBtn" />Select files</button>
           </div>
       );
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       const instance = this; // `this` doesn't get minified, `instance` does
       instance.handleClick = instance.handleClick.bind(instance);
       instance._inputNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(instance.refs.fileChooser);
       instance._buttonNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(instance.refs.selectBtn);
       instance.IE8_Events = !instance._buttonNode.addEventListener;
       if (instance.IE8_Events) {
           instance._buttonNode.attachEvent('onclick', instance.handleClick);
       }
       else {
           instance._buttonNode.addEventListener('click', instance.handleClick, true);
       }
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
       const instance = this; // `this` doesn't get minified, `instance` does
       if (instance.IE8_Events) {
           instance._buttonNode.detachEvent('onclick', instance.handleClick);
       }
       else {
           instance._buttonNode.removeEventListener('click', instance.handleClick, true);
       }
   }

   handleClick() {
       this._inputNode.click();
   }

}
```

Comment: This is incorrect - Firefox does allow simulating clicks

Comment: You need to make sure that you call fileRef.click inside the event loop based on the user action so `<Fake button onClick={ref.click()}/>` would work while if we put it inside an effect or some other side code that is not part of the event loop - it would not fire